# Spark kafka streaming - how to determine end of a batch

Tags: apache-spark

I am consuming from a Kafka topic by using Kafka Streaming. (kafka direct stream)
The data in this topic arrives after every 5 minutes from another source.
Now i need to process the data that arrives after every 5 minutes and convert that into a Spark DataFrame.

Now, stream is continuous flow of data.
My issue is , how do i determine that i am done reading first set of data that was loaded in Kafka topic? (So that i can convert that into DataFrame and start my work)

I know i can mention the batch interval( in JavaStreamingContext) to a certain number, but even then i can never be sure on how much time the source will take to push the data to the topic.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to not create a batch till all the data for the 5 minute worth of input is read.
Spark out of the box does not provide any API like that.

You can how ever use a sliding window on your received stream to achieve part of what you want. (See last example code)

The other way(harder way) is to implement your own `org.apache.spark.streaming.util.ManualClock` to achieve what you need.

ManualClock is a private class so the override happens within the name space.

```
package org.apache.spark.streaming

import org.apache.spark.util.ManualClock
  object ClockWrapper {
    def advance(ssc: StreamingContext, timeToAdd: Duration): Unit = {
      val manualClock = ssc.scheduler.clock.asInstanceOf[ManualClock]
    manualClock.advance(timeToAdd.milliseconds)
  }
}
```

Then in your own class

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ClockWrapper, Duration, Seconds, StreamingContext}
//elided.
  override def sparkConfig: Map[String, String] = {
    super.sparkConfig + ("spark.streaming.clock" -> "org.apache.spark.streaming.util.ManualClock")
   }

   def ssc: StreamingContext = _ssc

   def advanceClock(timeToAdd: Duration): Unit = {
     //Only if some other conditions are met..
     ClockWrapper.advance(_ssc, timeToAdd)
   }

   def advanceClockOneBatch(): Unit = {
     advanceClock(Duration(batchDuration.milliseconds))
   }
```

State based stream management can be done by using mapWithState API.

```
object StatefulStreamOperation {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("")
  // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
  ssc.checkpoint(".")

  val incoming: DStream[(batchTimeMultipleOf5Minute, UserClass)]
  val mappingFunc = (key: batchTime, incoming: Option[Int], state: State[UserClass]) => {
  //Do what ever you need to do to the data.
  //say (result, newState) = Some_Cool_operation(incoming, state) 
  state.update(newState)
  result
}

val stateDstream = dataDstream.mapWithState(
  StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).initialState(initialRDD))
//Do something with the result.
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

}
}

Comment: Is reading a big batch of data recommended though?
Also, can we do something like this :

Keep reading data from topic until we stop getting data, and then we declare end of the batch. Is there any provision in Spark for this kind of check?

Comment: You are right Amanpreet. I would try to use some state based streaming instead of going this approach. My answer was just saying that it can be done. (Not necessarily the best way to do it.)

Comment: I think you are right, state based streaming can be used. Can elaborate with a code sample, i can accept your answer then, Thanks